# Emberjs using helpers in attributes

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I want to do something like this:

```
<a target="_blank" {{bind-attr href="{{mailToHelper email}}"}}>
  <span>{{email}}</span>
</a>
```

The customer "mailToHelper" simply appends a "mailto:" string to the passed argument.

Yes, i can create a customer computed property but this feels a clear case of a view helper.

I couldn't find any docs on whether this is possible or not. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 2):

No you can't, helpers don't work in helpers.  You're better off writing a helper that generates the link

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/uvObiTEZ/1/edit

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('mailToHelper', function(email, options) {
  var mailTo = '<a target="_blank" href="mailto:' + email + '">';
  mailTo += "<span>" + email + "</span></a>";
  return new Handlebars.SafeString(mailTo);
});

{{mailToHelper email}}
```

Comment: The problem is that locks the markup that can go inside the '<a>' tag. Often, you might have more than "email" to go as the anchor text of the "a" tag.

Comment: @Rajat You can add another parameter to the helper. Anyway it seems the best way for now is to use another property with `mailto:` prefix.

Comment: @Rajat htmlbars will allow what you'd like to do. Its currently under active development. You can read about it [here](https://github.com/tildeio/htmlbars)